# t-SNE vs mm t-SNE

Tags: r, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I have a question concerning t-SNE algorithm implementations in R. I have a dataset whose dimensionality is about 300, and I want to visualize it in 3 dimensions. I tried the `Rtsne` package, it's working well and it's quite quick (2000 iterations in 2 minutes). Then I heard about the multiple maps t-SNE algorithm. If I understand correctly, in my case it somehow gives the possibility to add a 4th dimension to the visualisation sub-space by fixing the number of possible values of this 4th dimension: let's say I set the parameter `number of maps` to 2, then I have 2 3D-spaces. But, if I set this parameter to 1, then it should return an equivalent result of t-SNE (albeit, not completely equal because of random initializations).

The problem is that using multiple map t-SNE (using the `mmtsne` library) takes too much time to compute iterations, even with `no_maps` set to 1. Is that normal? Is there any way I can speed up things?

Comment: Hi mhaddad, welcome to CV! On this site there's no need to say "thank you" at the end of your post - it might seem rude at first, but it's part of the philosophy of this site ([tour]) to "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" and it means future readers of your question don't need to read through the pleasantries.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [Rtsne](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rtsne/index.html) explicitly mentions it is a wrapper around the *fast* t-SNE, i.e., the [Barnes-Hut implementation](https://github.com/lvdmaaten/bhtsne/) from the original author, which is in C++. The documentation for [mmtsne](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mmtsne/index.html) describes itself as a port of the Matlab implementation of multiple-maps t-SNE, which means it is probably written in R and does not include the Barnes-Hut approximation. This is probably where the performance differences come from.